# Inserir registros selecionados em outra tabela

Tags: php, mysql, json

Preciso exportar dados de uma tabela que tenho em nossa intranet para uma tabela na internet, criei uma tabela onde mostro os eventos e nessa o usuário pode escolher os que deseja exportar através de seleção de checkbox.

Passo o(s) id(s) para uma página onde faço o resgate e busco todos os dados relacionados e faço um retorno JSON, gostaria da opinião se estou no caminho certo no modo como estou fazendo isso, no caso a exportação de dados.

Vejam a página de processo:

```
<?php 

require_once("../db/conexao.php");

// Recebendo o array com os ID´S
$checkboxes = $_GET['list'];

$arr = array(); 
$arr['flag'] = 0;   

// laço para buscar e-mail e efetuar envio
foreach($checkboxes as $id) {

    // buscando registro(s)
    mysql_select_db($database_conexao, $conexao);
    $query_rsRegistro = "SELECT FROM tecnicoEventos WHERE idEvento = $id ";
    $rsRegistro = mysql_query($query_rsRegistro, $conexao) or die(mysql_error());
    $row_rsRegistro = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsRegistro);
    $totalRows_rsRegistro = mysql_num_rows($rsRegistro);

    // resgatando valores da seleção
    $IdEvento = $row_rsRegistro['idEvento'];
    $IdUnidade = $row_rsRegistro['idUnidade'];
    $Data = $row_rsRegistro['data'];
    $Nome = $row_rsRegistro['nome'];
    $Evento = $row_rsRegistro['evento'];
    $Publico = $row_rsRegistro['publico'];
    $Participantes = $row_rsRegistro['participantes'];
    $Local = $row_rsRegistro['local'];
    $Horario = $row_rsRegistro['horario'];
    $Carga = $row_rsRegistro['carga'];
    $Status = $row_rsRegistro['status'];
    $Responsavel = $row_rsRegistro['responsavel'];
    $DataCadastro = $row_rsRegistro['dataCadastro'];
    $AtivoSite = $row_rsRegistro['ativoSite'];
    $Img = $row_rsRegistro['img'];
    $TumbImg = $row_rsRegistro['tumbImg'];
    $Atualizado = $row_rsRegistro['atualizado'];        

        if ($totalRows_rsRegistro > 0) {

            // Conectando ao banco de dados e realizando a inserção de dados
            require_once('Connections/conWeb.php');;

            /* Inserindo dados no banco de dados */ 
            mysql_select_db($database_conWebCocari, $conWebCocari);
            $sqlCand = "INSERT INTO tecnicoEventos ( 
                idEvento, 
                idUnidade, 
                data, 
                nome, 
                evento, 
                publico, 
                participantes, 
                local, 
                horario, 
                carga, 
                status, 
                responsavel, 
                dataCadastro, 
                ativoSite, 
                img, 
                tumbimg, 
                atualizado ) 
            VALUES (
                $IdEvento, 
                $IdUnidade, 
                '$Data', 
                '$Nome',                            
                '$Evento', 
                '$Publico', 
                $Participantes, 
                '$Local', 
                '$Horario', 
                '$Carga', 
                $Status, 
                '$Responsavel', 
                '$DataCadastro', 
                $AtivoSite, 
                '$Img', 
                '$TumbImg', 
                '$Atualizado')";                                
            $resultInsert = mysql_query($sqlCand, $conWeb) or die ("Erro Inserindo Registro: " . mysql_error());    

        }

        $resultado = $resultInsert;

} // fim do foreach



if ($resultado == 1) {
    $arr['result'] = 'TRUE';
    $arr['msg'] = 'Os registros foram inseridos com sucesso';       
    $arr['flag'] = 1;   
} else {
    $arr['result'] = 'FALSE';
    $arr['msg'] = 'Os registros não foram inseridos, por favor verifique';      
    $arr['flag'] = 0;       
}

$arr = array_map('htmlentities',$arr);  
echo json_encode($arr);
```

?>

Comment: Todos os campos do select serão inseridos na outra tabela?

Comment: Isso mesmo, todos os campos.

Comment: Veja se minha resposta resolve seu caso.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma solução seria usar INSERT com SELECT.

Exemplo:

```
INSERT INTO banco.tabela-destino (campo1, campo2, campo3...)
SELECT campo1,campo2,campo3... FROM banco.tabela-origem;
```

Atente-se para que os campos estejam na mesma seqüência tanto na instrução INSERT quanto na instrução SELECT pois é seguida a seqüência de campos em ambas as instruções. Também não se esqueça do ponto e vírgula no final da última instrução. Imprescindível.

Fonte: [[1]](http://codare.net/2008/05/17/mysql-insert-com-select-na-mesma-query/)

Comment: +1, já que você quer colocar somente eventos selecionados pelo usuário, passe os ids dos eventos e use `IN` na sua query.

Comment: Como vou conectar em duas bases de dados diferentes como poderei fazer isso usando o exemplo do Insert com Select?

Comment: Obrigado ao @NULL e ao gcarvalho97 pelas contribuições, me ajudaram muito.